# I just want to send textarea entry as a post using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<p><h3>Enter your SQL query below:</h3>
<form method="post" action="http://212.47.247.139/challenge/ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D" id="my-form">
    <textarea id='text1' class='sql' name='submission' rows=10 cols=120></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="blogSubmit" onclick="getText()">
    <br>
</form>
</p>
<script>
function getText() {
        // var str=document.getElementById("text1").value;
        // alert(str + "i did it");
        // var d = $('#text1').serialize();

        $.ajax('ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D', {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            
            data: {submission: JSON.stringify($('#text1').val())},
            success: function(data) {
                success_callback(data);
                console.log("success " + data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
            type: 'POST'
        })
    }
</script>
```

In the text area, if I type in "sk" and click submit button, then i see in the request payload under network tab: `submission=%22sk%22`. Where is the %22 coming from btw? And the query string parameters say `submission: %7B7D`

But then i get the error message: `Error: Expected POST success Error: Expected POST`

If I take out the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`line and try to submit, i get an error message saying "Missing or empty submission prop in json
success Missing or empty submission prop in json".

If I add the `dataType: 'JSON'` to the ajax, then I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0".

```
function getText() {
    // var str=document.getElementById("text1").value;
    // alert(str + "i did it");
    // var d = $('#text1').serialize();

    $.ajax('ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D', {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {submission: JSON.stringify($('#text1').val())},
        success: function(data) {
            success_callback(data);
            console.log("success " + data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        type: 'POST'
    })
}
```

Ive been stuck on this for awhile. I dont understand what i should do. I just want to send textarea entry as a post using ajax

Comment: You are telling server you are sending json but you aren't. jQuery will serialize your data object to uri form encoding

Comment: You are converting the data to a JSON string   sk => "sk"  and that is getting uri encoded %22sk%22. It is the equivalent of this:  encodeURI(JSON.stringify('sk'))

Comment: the submission %7B%7D is plainly right there in your ajax url   'ajax.php?submission=%7B%7D'

Comment: Having two submission parameters is likely going to be received as an array of both pieces of information on the server side: submission = [ '%7B%7D', '%22sk%22' ]

Comment: You should be performing JSON.stringify on the entire data object, not pieces of data inside the data object.  data: JSON.stringify({ submission: $('#text1').val() })

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your input type to submit, and replace `submission_url.php` with the route you want to submit the form to.

```js
<form method="post" action="#" id="my-form">
    <textarea id='text1' class='sql' name='submission' rows=10 cols=120></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="blogSubmit" onclick="getText()">
    <br>
</form>

<script>
$('#my-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let text1 = $(this).find('#text1').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submission_url.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'submission': text1
        },
        success: function(data){
            res = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```